# centos firewalld ipset blacklist ip cidrs on specific ports

Tags: centos, firewalld, ipset

I found this link regarding how to set up a blacklist xml file for firewalld:
[ipset instructions](http://www.firewalld.org/2015/12/ipset-support)
Clear enough, but I don't want to drop access for all ports, just 80 and 443. Suggestions? (BTW the firewalld forum doesn't seem to be adding new users.)

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the blacklist ipset just as in the link you mentioned, but instead of using

```
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule source ipset=blacklist drop'
```

to tie the blacklist to the rest of the ruleset, use something like this:

```
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule source ipset=blacklist service name="http" drop'
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule source ipset=blacklist service name="https" drop'
```

I've found that Fedora has [a nice document](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/FirewalldRichLanguage) on `firewalld` rich rules.